# Python requests.get TikTok returns b''

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to get the html of a TikTok video page and requests is returning b'' instead of the pages entire HTML. This works on other sites and even the tiktok home page (https://www.tiktok.com/) but not on video pages. Can someone try out my code and let me know what is going on? Also, I got the return code and it was 200.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'user-agent': MY USER AGENT,
}

page = requests.get("https://www.tiktok.com/@thatlittlepuff/video/7160116843611475246",headers=headers)

print(page.content)
```

```
b''
```

I tried to do other tiktok video pages but those don't work either

Comment: Sending you an empty response back is their way to tell you that they don't want to be scraped.

Comment: I get regular HTML using your code. Are you blocked by tt?

Answer (score 0):

If you fail to [create convincing headers](https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-fake-and-rotate-user-agents-using-python-3/#therightwaytorotateuseragentsinanyprogram), consider using something like [ScrapingAnt](https://scrapingant.com/)

```py
api_url = "https://api.scrapingant.com/v2/general"
page_url = "https://www.tiktok.com/@thatlittlepuff/video/7160116843611475246"
myKey_sa = YOUR_API_TOKEN # register on https://scrapingant.com/ and paste here

page = requests.get(f'{api_url}?url={page_url}&x-api-key={myKey_sa}')

print(page.content)
```

the free tier allows a limited number of requests, and it's quite slow, but if you're not going to be making a huge number of requests, it really simplifies matters.

If you *are* going to be making a large number of requests, consider [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) instead.